# How to display a single record from json server db.json from user input

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am taking user input from input component and now based on that input i want to display his information on display component in angular. Different user records are present in json server db.json.

How can I do this??

I tried many ways like using activated route but not getting any display output what to do now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to go on but from what I understand you have two components, in one you have the input which takes in a certain input from a user, and then you have a secondary component which displays data that is fetched from db.json, which defers based on user input.

If so you can try using parent -> child component structure and use @Input to pass the relevant data.

For example your parent component (where you get the user input) can look something like this:

```
<input id="user-input" type="text" [formControl]="userInput">

<app-display-component [item]="userInput"></app-display-component>
```

And you can accept the passed input value like below in the display component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; // First, import Input
export class DisplayComponent{
  @Input() item = ''; 
}
```

After that you can use this passed input value as you like to fetch the data from db.json as you see fit. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes this was helpful issue is resolved

Comment: Cheers Mate! I think this issue can be marked as solved to be used by others for reference then.